# Wortreihenfolge in »weil du es bist«

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Welche der beiden Formen ist richtig:

> Weil du es bist (weil du's bist)

oder:

> Weil es du bist (weil's du bist)

Oder ist nur eine der beiden richtig?

Comment: Remember that "weils" and "dus" are not correct!

Comment: @Alex.S Yes they are! ([§ 97](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf). § 96(2) trifft nicht zu, denn weder in *weils* noch in *dus* ist das Wort schwer les-/erkennbar.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im Deutschen herrscht in der Regel freie Wortreihenfolge, solange man die Stellung des Verbs (hier in einem Nebensatz: Verb zuletzt) beachtet. Dennoch unterscheiden sich die verschiedenen möglichen Varianten hinsichtlich Betonung einzelner Fragmente, und etwas, das sich nur sehr grob als *Spannung* wiedergeben lässt.

In »weil du es bist« ist die Reihenfolge der Satzglieder Konjunktion – Subjekt – Prädikativ – Verb. Das ist die unmarkierte, spannungsärmste Möglichkeit, den Satz zu bauen, – und dementsprechend auch die üblichste.

In »weil es du bist«, haben Prädikativ und Subjekt die Plätze getauscht: Konjunktion – Prädikativ – Subjekt – Verb. Das ist hier eine unübliche Satzstellung; erlaubt, aber spannungsbehaftet und betonend. Ich würde sie vermeiden. Grammatikalisch und syntaktisch ist sie allerdings korrekt, wenngleich nicht bevorzugt.

Answer (score 3):

"Weil du es bist" und "Weil es du bist" sind beide richtig, obwohl man das 2. sehr selten hört, ich würde deshalb das 1. ("Weil du es bist") verwenden.